# What are common suffix and prefix code guidelines?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

What are some commonly used suffixes and prefixes that are used in SystemVerilog code? I'm referring to the code guidelines for SystemVerilog elements such as variables, parameters, classes, etc.

Here are a few I'm aware of:

Prefix:

- `m_` - member (of this class)
- `cg_` - covergroup name

Suffix:

- `_if` - interface
- `_t` - typedef
- `_s` - struct
- `_u` - union
- `_e` - enum
- `_h` - variable name which is a reference (handle) to a class
- `_pkg` - package
- `_c` - class OR constraint (pick one and go with it)
- `_cb` - clocking
- `_mp` - modport
- `_cg` - covergroup (this one could be a prefix or suffix)

Answer (score 0):

Parameters like constants in other languages should be kept UPPERCASE. Everything else is lower case. Use _ as a delimiter, avoid CamelCase.

For RTL suffix,

```
_n for active low signals.
_a for asynchronous signals.

rst_an implies active low asynchronous reset.
```

These are the commonest ones I have come across, in the interest of creating the best answer include in others if you like or edit this answer to add more.

Answer (score 0):

For RTL suffix, I have seen _l as an alternative to _n.  _i and _o make appearances for input and output, although this makes it harder for autoconnect scripts to do their work.

For prefixes, src_dst_signal_name (where src and dst are short names for modules) is a common methodology.

Above all remember not everyone follows these (or any) conventions, one of my more embarrassing bugs was a chip where the interface didn't work because the incoming signals were active low but had no suffixes on them.